# When I run the npm install command under drupal 10 custom theme folder

Tags: drupal-themes

When I run the npm install command under drupal custom theme folder
I am using Drupal 10 version
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnN2e.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnN2e.png)

tried with deleting package-lock.json file
and run this
npm cache clean --force
I am getting that issue
Which i have added in that screenshot

Comment: What is "that issue"? Please share more details, like any error message you are facing **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Actually  I am trying to do the local setup in project (Its Drupal 10)
Design is not getting properly so my team mate suggests to do npm install under my custom theme folder then after u will get proper design I tried as per discussion But  I am getting below issue when I run the npm command under my custom theme folder and I have attached screenshot above pls look into it and do the needful

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Also, share "below issue" **in text form**, not hidden in a screenshot

Comment: does your local have python path setup for use?

Answer (score 0):

Ah the wonderful world of Drupal themes, where you go to NPM install to make one small change and the entire front end setup is outdated / broken / won't install.

node-gyp errors are often caused by incompatible node versions, so perhaps if this is an old theme you have newer node versions installed causing an issue.

When people get a node-gyp error one of:

- Deleting node-modules
- Deleting ~/.node-gyp
- Removing HOME/.node-gyp
- Restarting machine
- Changing node version

Can get it to run.

Alternatively, if this is an old theme, it may be worth keeping your local setup with the latest node installed, and instead look to upgrade any build tools - gulp, sass etc re-writing certain things where required.

Comment: @kaviyarasan any success?